# How to add up a row of values in an array and move to the previous key PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like the value that has an o in the following example to be added to the key before the first key that has a value with an o in the array. Like this:

```
$arr = array(
0 => 'apple',
1 => 'pear',
2 => 'orange',
3 => 'octopus',
4 => 'pineapple'
)


$arr = array(
0 => 'apple',
1 => 'pearorangeoctopus',
2 => 'Pineapple'
)
```

But the amount of rows that has an o can be variable and multiple times in there..

```
$arr = array(

    0 => 'apple',
    1 => 'pear',
    2 => 'orange',
    3 => 'octopus',
    4 => 'pineapple',
    5 => 'blueberry',
    6 => 'pumpkin',
    7 => 'chocolate',
    8 => 'icecream'

)


$arr = array(
0 => 'apple',
1 => 'pearorangeoctopus',
2 => 'pineapple',
3 => 'blueberry',
4 => 'pumpkinchocolate',
5 => 'icecream'
)
```

anyone got an idea? :)

Comment: be careful with the spelling... array() not aray..

Comment: What if the first value has an o in it?

Comment: Why did `chocolate` get concatenated in the 2nd example?

Comment: That does not compute (your second example kind of contradicts the first). Didn't you make an error there? Otherwise there's no logic in your "problem" so it's impossible to solve it.

Comment: Oops.. sorry you're right, array() and yes i also made an error in the second example. It should be:

$arr = array(

0 => 'apple',
1 => 'pear',
2 => 'orange',
3 => 'octopus',
4 => 'pineapple',
5 => 'blueberry',
6 => 'pumpkin',
7 => 'chocolate',
8 => 'icecream'

)
becomes:
$arr = aray(
0 => 'apple',
1 => 'pearorangeoctopus',
2 => 'pineapple',
3 => 'blueberry',
4 => 'pumpkinchocolate',
5 => 'icecream'
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array();
$currentIndex = 0;
$item = $arr[$currentIndex];
while ($currentIndex < count($arr)) {
    $nextItem = $arr[$currentIndex+1];
    if (strpos($nextItem, 'o') !== false) {
        $item .= $nextItem;
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $item;
        $item = $arr[$currentIndex+1];
    }
    $currentIndex++;
}
```

This is probably what you're looking for, if the solution for your second case is :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=> "apple"
  [1]=> "pearorangeoctopus"
  [2]=> "pineapple"
  [3]=> "blueberry"
  [4]=> "pumpkinchocolate"
  [5]=> "icecream"
}
```

BTW Just to be clear : the code needed to get rid of the Notice (Undefined offset) is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$arr = array(...);

$new_arr = array();

$o_index = false;
foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
  if($item[0]=='o'){
    if(!$o_index)
      $o_index = $key-1;
    $new_arr[$o_index] .= $item
  }else{
    $new_arr[$key] = $item;
  }
}
```

Have in mind that this will make problems if your keys are not consecutive numbers or the first key starts with 'o'